# Debugging node js with node-debug

Tags: javascript, node.js

Starting of with node js and I thought it would be a good idea to debug the application.

Im running node js on my ubuntu virtual machine.

This is the node script

```
var http = require('http');
var port = 8080;

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    res.end('hello world!');
}).listen(port, '192.168.137.2');
```

And then I start with the node-inspector.

```
node-debug index.js
```

The chrome browser fires up and instantly breaks on first line.

```
var http = require('http');
```

Then as I resume the program I get the following error message in the console.

```
Error: listen EADDRINUSE
at errnoException (net.js:904:11)
at Server._listen2 (net.js:1042:14)
at listen (net.js:1064:10)
at net.js:1146:9
at exports.lookup.callback (dns.js:72:18)
at process._tickCallback (node.js:419:13)
at Module.runMain [as _onTimeout] (module.js:499:11)
at Timer.listOnTimeout [as ontimeout] (timers.js:112:15)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Everything works fine when I just run

```
node --debug index.js
```

But if I do that I dont know how to debug it..

Comment: Does it work if you change the port, e.g. 8081?

Comment: haha yes.. I feel really stupid now, I should have tried that. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Tried changing port like Simone-Cu said. And that worked..

```
var port = 8081;
```

Comment: Alternatively, you can make `node-debug` use another port besides 8080: `node-debug -p 8081 index.js`